# Since you can store a Bag Holding or Handy Haversack in a Pathfinder Pouch, how the do these containers' weights factor in?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weight

Since you can store a Bag Holding or Handy Haversack in a Pathfinder Pouch, how the do these containers' weights factor in?

A Pathfinder Pouch has vol cap of 2 cubic feet & weight cap of 10 pounds; this can fit the Handy Haversack and or a Minor Bag of Holding, since they weigh under 10 pounds. How does this affect the standard Bags of Holding whose weight ranges from the basic 15 pound Bag of Holding I, to the Bag of Holding IV at 60 pounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Compute each extradimensional space's capacity independently

The contents of each extradimensional storage space are each, in turn, on different planes, so the weights of their contents don't counting toward the maximum capacities of the extradimensional spaces in which the containers themselves are kept.

To analogize, in your first apartment you put a door to a second apartment. Inside that second apartment you put a door to a third apartment. The first apartment cares what's in that second apartment only insofar as how much the door to the second apartment weighs. Likewise, the second apartment cares what's in the third apartment only insofar as how much that door to the third apartment weighs. (Other stuff, of course, can be tossed into any apartment, but that stuff counts only toward that apartment's weight as that stuff is, like the door, *only* in *that* apartment.)

Thus a [*pathfinder's pouch*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pathfinder-pouch/) can store extradimensionally up to 10 lb. and itself weighs 1 lb. A *minor [bag of holding](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding)* can store extradimensionally up to 50 lbs. and itself weighs 3 lbs. A [*handy haversack*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-handy-haversack/) can hold in its three pockets extradimensionally up to 120 lbs. and itself weighs 5 lbs. Combined, a user can keep inside his *pathfinder's pouch* a *minor bag of holding* inside of which is a full *handy haversack*.

The only real consequence of doing this is that while an extradimensional space is inside another extradimensional space, the space that's inside the space is inaccessible. For example, a creature can't wriggle into its *bag of holding* and, while within the *bag*, access there the contents of his *handy haversack*.

[Wondrous Items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/) on Extradimensional Spaces says

> A number of spells and magic items utilize extradimensional spaces, such as *rope trick*, *bags of holding*, *handy haversacks*, and *portable holes*. These spells and magic items create a tiny pocket space that does not exist in any dimension. Such items do not function, however, inside another extradimensional space. If placed inside such a space, they cease to function until removed from the extradimensional space. For example, if a *bag of holding* is brought into a *rope trick*, the contents of the *bag of holding* become inaccessible until the *bag of holding* is taken outside the *rope trick*. The only exception to this is when a *bag of holding* and a [*portable hole*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/portable-hole) interact, forming a rift to the Astral Plane, as noted in their descriptions.

Some GMs will warn against putting *any* extradimensional space inside another extradimensional space, citing the possibility of explosive consequences. If in such a campaign, this player strongly recommends against such a practice until the accuracy of such consequences can be verified. However, like in the above quotation, in most campaigns, such explosions and implosions are usually only a byproduct of stuffing a *bag of holding et al.* into a [*portable hole*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/portable-hole/) or *vice versa* rather than nesting multiple *bag of holding*-like items.

Comment: While understand this, i think I phrased the question the wrong way. I want to hide the fact I have a lot adventuring gear with me as well loot, being a rogue I tend to pick up a lot valuable during a heist. I'd like to appear like as have nothing but a pouch on me if ever get caught, and empty one at that as a Pathfinders Pouch functions much as a Bag of Concealment. I would like to know what would happen to my Pathfinder's Pouch with a 2 cuft vol & 10 lb cap if put put a standard 2ft x 4ft  Bag of Holding I that weighs 15 lbs. Will it not fit or not work at all since it over the weight cap.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver O, I get it, and that's legit. Essentially, this answer's saying, "Worry about what's in the space and not what's in the space in the space." Reread paragraph 3. (To be clear, should I add something about the dimensions of a *bag of holding* itself *not* being cubic even while its capacity is measured in cubic ft.? That is, it's like a potato sack—it doesn't even take up 1 cu. ft. because it's mainly flat by nature!)

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed to know.